# Find the number of elements in sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a battle, $75 \%$ of the troops lost an eye, $60\%$ troops lost an arm and $80\%$ lost a leg. If each troop has at least one type of injury and the percentage of troops having loss of exactly two types is $55$, find the percentage of the troops having all types of loss at the same time.

**My attempt:**

Suppose,  $E$ := set of troops who lost an eye, $A$ := set of troops who lost an arm and
$L$ := set of troops who lost an leg. Now,

$$n(E∪A∪L)=n(E)+n(A)+n(L)-n(E∩A)-n(E∩L)-n(A∩L)+n(E∩A∩L)$$
$$100=75+60+80-55-55-55+n(E∩A∩L)$$
$$n(E∩A∩L)=50$$

But the answer is $30$. What am I doing wrong here ?

My second attempt

$$n(E∩A∩L ̅ )+n(E∩A ̅∩L)+n(E ̅∩A∩L)=55$$
$$n(E∩(A∩L ̅ ))=n(E∩A)$$
$$n(E∩A ̅∩L)=n(E∩L)$$
$$n(E ̅∩A∩L)=n(A∩L)$$

$$n(E∩A)+n(E∩L)+n(A∩L)=55$$
$$n(E∪A∪L)=n(E)+n(A)+n(L)-n(E∩A)-n(E∩L)-n(A∩L)+n(E∩A∩L)$$
$$100=75+60+80-55+n(E∩A∩L)$$
$$n(E∩A∩L)=100-160$$
$$n(E∩A∩L)=-60$$

which gives me negative percentage. what am i missing here.

Comment: I read "*the percentage of troops having loss of exactly two types*" to mean that $n(E\cap A\cap L^c)+n(E\cap A^c\cap L)+n(E^c\cap A\cap L) = 55$, i.e. that the chance of having lost two appendages *of any kind* is $55\%$ be it an arm and a leg or an arm and an eye etc with all of these grouped together... not that each case individually is $55$.

Comment: How do i solve this now? I am more confused now.

Comment: Note that $n(E\cap A\cap L^c) = n(E\cap A)-n(E\cap A\cap L)$.  You can do similar for the others.

Comment: @JMoravitz any refrence or book where proof is given of n(E∩A∩Lc)=n(E∩A)−n(E∩A∩L). Thanks for the help. It helped me lot.

Comment: It follows from the fact that as sets $(E\cap A\cap L^c)\cup (E\cap A\cap L)=(E\cap A)$, that they are disjoint, and that $n(~\cdot~)$ is subadditive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n(E\cup A\cup L)=n(E)+n(A)+n(L)-n(E\cap A)-n(E\cap L)-n(A\cap L)+n(E\cap A\cap L)$

---

$=n(E)+n(A)+n(L)\underbrace{-n(E\cap A)\color{blue}{+n(E\cap A\cap L)}}_{-n(E\cap A\cap L^c)} - n(E\cap L)\color{blue}{+n(E\cap A\cap L)} - \\n(A\cap L)\color{blue}{+n(E\cap A\cap L)} + n(E\cap A\cap L)\color{red}{-3n(E\cap A\cap L)}$

---

$=n(E)+n(A)+n(L)\underbrace{-n(E\cap A\cap L^c)-n(E\cap A^c\cap L)-n(E^c\cap A\cap L)}_{-\text{exactly two injuries}}-2n(E\cap A\cap L)$

---

$100=75+60+80-55-2n(E\cap A\cap L)$

---

So, $n(E\cap A\cap L) = \dfrac{75+60+80-55-100}{2}=\dfrac{60}{2}=30$

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake here is your assuming that since in the question it is given

> percentage of troops having loss of exactly two types is 55

Here this doesn't mean $ n ( E ∩ A ) $ or for any other matter that this is true. The above line meant when they are together not individually. Writing in maths it means

$$ n(E^c∩A∩L) + n(E∩A^c∩L) + n(E∩A∩L^c) = 55  $$

Comment: HOw to solve this now form here?

Comment: Just refer JMoravitz answer. If you need more help I can definitely help @SagarRawal